# Building a C++ project that links to a Haskell library, using Shake and Stack

Tags: c++, haskell, dynamic-linking, haskell-stack, shake-build-system

I'm trying to build a simple C++ project (an executable) that calls a Haskell function,
using Shake for the build script and calling Stack from within the script to build the Haskell library.

Let's say the Haskell library is called `haskell-simple-lib`.

The shake script calls `stack install haskell-simple-lib` which outputs an `.so` file: `libHShaskell-simple-lib-*version*-*unique identifier*.so`

My Shake rules depends on filenames, and so I can't use the aforementioned name as I don't know in advance what the unique identifier will be. And so, the Shake script runs a `cp` on the file to `_build/libHShaskell-simple-lib.so`

The link options for the C++ executable has `-L_build` and `-lhaskell-simple-lib`.

When I try to run the executable I get an error saying:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libHShaskell-simple-lib-0.1.0.0-8DkaSm3F3d44RUd03fOuDx-ghc7.10.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But, if I rename the file I copied to `_build`, to the original name that `stack install` outputted (the one with the unique identifier), the executable runs correctly.

One would think that all I need to do is to simply `cp` the file to `_build` without erasing the unique identifier from the name, however I need to know the name of the `.so` file in advance for the shake script.

I don't understand why when the executable is run the original .so filename is searched for. The link flag doesn't mention the fullname of the `.so` that `stack install` outputted, only `libHShaskell-simple-lib`.
Could it be that the original name is embedded in the .so file? If so, how does one go about solving this issue?

EDIT:
I'm aware this could be solved using a dummy file, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Should you be running `stack install`, or rather `stack build`? You can also pass the `--copy-bins` flag to `stack`, so that it can copy the files by itself without invoking a shake `cp`.

Comment: `stack build --copy-bins` is identical to `stack install`.
If I use only that instead of `cp` the .so is not renamed, and the shake script fails, as mentioned above.
But Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The original identifier is embedded in the `.so`. I don't remember all the details, but I do know that I've solved such problems using [`rpath`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) twiddling in the past.